# Why my test "propType == typeof(ObservableCollection<string>)" fails?

Tags: c#, generics, observablecollection, typeof

I got a Type whose FullName is :

```
"System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"
```

The thing is that I'd like to test if my Type is an ObservableCollection of string (in the current case, it is). So here is my code :

```
if (propertyType.GetType() == typeof(ObservableCollection<string>))
```

but it seems to fail and I don't understand why :/

I had this code thats works :

```
if (propertyType.Namespace == "System.Collections.ObjectModel" && propertyType.Name == "ObservableCollection`1")
{
    //We are dealing with an ObservableCollection
    var args = propertyType.GetGenericArguments();
    if (args.Count() != 0 && args[0] == typeof(string))
    {
        //MyCode for ObservableCollection<string>
    }
}
```

but I don't feel like it's optimal and considering that I'll have to handle other collections (IEnumerable, List, etcetc...) of other Types (int, bool, etcetc...) this doesnt fit well :(

Comment: Could you add in your question the property declaration and how you fill the propertyType variable? Because it should work.

Comment: I'm doing a test with "typeof" so I don't have to use "GetType()" on my Type :(

Comment: You sure that's all of your code? Is this Observable collection a peroprty of a class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At a guess, remove the extra `.GetType()`:

```
if (propertyType == typeof(ObservableCollection<string>))
```

since `propertyType.GetType()` is probably some derivative of `System.Type` (such as `System.RuntimeType`).

Comment: oh my god you're right... :( that works I forgot I was doing a test with "typeof" :(

Comment: @GuillaumeSlashy sometimes all you need is fresh eyes ;p

Comment: Oo . How did I fail to see this. Hmm.. Ok, never attempt to go to stackoverflow too soon after waking up.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
if (propertyType is ObservableCollection<string>)
{ }
```

Comment: propertyType will be of type `Type`; a `Type` is **never** an `ObservableCollection<string>`; I would *expect* the compiler will spot this and give an "always false" warning

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that you are doing propertyType.GetType() to actually get the type and assumed propertyType is not a Type.